# Storm not found for submitting topology?

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm

I had problem in storm jar while submitting topology as i'm stand on

```
 storm starter/src/jvm/storm/starter/
```

i wrote

```
storm jar ExclamationTopology.jar storm.starter.ExclamationTopology arg1
```

typed

storm command not found

i want to know what's the wrong ?

and what's the difference between 
storm jar ....
and

```
mvn -f m2-pom.xml compile exec:java -Dstorm.topology=storm.starter.ExclamationTopology
```

are both submitting a topology ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storm Command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714878/storm-command-not-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you placed the Storm *bin* directory on your path as described [here](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Setting-up-development-environment).

And yes, you can run a topology with Maven (described [here](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter#maven)) or with the *storm* command (described [here](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Tutorial)).

Comment: And you shut down all your windows and tried again? And did an echo on the path and all that? At this point, your problem seems less about Storm and more about running a command line action.

Comment: Ok i guess that.it worked but it cannot find the class can you tell me the exact path should i write and can i cut the file of java like Word Count Topology.java from the whole file "storm starter " and put the path of it ? I'm new in storm and it's first time to submit topology

Comment: Since it worked, please upvote and/or accept this answer. Then write a new question to address your new problem.

Comment: i can't vote cause i need to have 14 reputation as i'm new in Stack overflow